Splitting field of $x^6 + 1$ over $F_2$
So I want to find the splitting field of $g(x)=x^6+1$ over $F_2$ and the degree of the extension, so what I have done is the following
$$g(x)=x^6+1=(x^3)^2+1^2=(x^3+1)^2=(x+1)^2(x^2+x+1)^2$$
So we see that $1$ is a root of $g$, so I need to find the roots of
$x^2+x+1$ but this polynomial has no roots in $F_2$, but I know that it has two complex roots, so the splitting field would be
$F_2(\alpha_1,\alpha_2)$ where $\alpha_1,\alpha_2$ are the complex roots, and the degree $2$ since the quadratic polynomial is minimal. So in particular we should have
$K=F_2(\alpha_1,\alpha_2)$ but I don't know how to indentify this field with a finite one, and i'm not sure if this procedure is correct. So any help is aprreciated.

Not sure if this'll be of any help, but the splitting field $\mathbb{F}_2[x]/(x^2-x+1)$ can simply be viewed as introducing the relation $x^2=x-1$ into $\mathbb{F}_2[x].$ (Your use of the term "complex numbers" doesn't sit too well with me, so thought maybe rewording your question could be useful.)

The term "complex roots" is problematic, since we are in the realm of finite fields, not complex numbers.
For any irreducible quadratic polynomial, to get the splitting field, we only need to add one root, thus the answer is $$\mathbb F_2[\alpha_1]=\mathbb F_2[x]/(x^2-x+1)\simeq\mathbb F_4$$

Thanks for the clarification, so I wasn't understanding the finite fields too well. Just a quick question, how do we know that $\mathbb F_2[x]/(x^2-x+1)$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb F_4$?

All finite fields of equal size are isomorphic to each other. $[\mathbb F_2[\alpha_1]:\mathbb F_2]=2$, hence $|\mathbb F_2[\alpha_1]|=2^2=4$.
